# ffmpeg encode timestamp framerate seems to skip frames

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate

I'm attempting to make a video that has the timestamp (from movie start) shown on the frame. I'm doing this with the following:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 3600 -i /path/to/my.png -s 1280x720 -vf drawtext="fontfile=/path/to/my.ttf:fontcolor=white: timecode='00\:00\:00;00': r='30000/1001': text='': fontsize=148: x=190: y=260:" -c:v libx264 -vb 1000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast -f mp4 -r 30 -y out.mp4`

The first frame starts with the timestamp `00:00:00;00` and the next `00:00:00;01` and so on until we get to the one minute mark, where the timestamps go from `00:00:59;29` to `00:01:00;02`, which seemingly is skipping two frames. No matter how much I mess around with both the input framerate and the output framerate, I get the same results. I've tried `-r 29.97` in both places.

edit:
the full output -

```
ffmpeg version 2.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 11 2014 20:59:04 with Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) 
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-ffplay
  libavutil      52. 48.101 / 52. 48.101
  libavcodec     55. 39.101 / 55. 39.101
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libavresample   1.  1.  0 /  1.  1.  0
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from 'a.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, pal8, 1904x1232, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[libx264 @ 0x7fe479800600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x7fe479800600] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7fe479800600] 264 - core 125 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=30 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=1000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 1000 kb/s, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=13780 fps= 35 q=-1.0 Lsize=   57239kB time=00:07:39.26 bitrate=1021.0kbits/s
video:57076kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.285284%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] frame I:56    Avg QP: 2.82  size:706101
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] frame P:3473  Avg QP: 7.90  size:  2664
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] frame B:10251 Avg QP:14.77  size:   942
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0% 99.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] mb I  I16..4: 15.2% 10.9% 73.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.2%  P16..4:  0.8%  0.1%  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:98.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.2%  0.1%  0.3%  direct: 0.1%  skip:99.3%  L0:49.2% L1:43.3% BI: 7.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] final ratefactor: 5.65
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] 8x8 transform intra:9.1% inter:16.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 95.4% 97.6% 97.1% inter: 0.4% 0.5% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 35% 16% 31% 19%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 14% 13%  4%  6%  9%  5%  8%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 13% 11%  7%  7%  8%  7% 10%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 38% 18% 34%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] ref P L0: 79.1% 20.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] ref B L0: 78.4% 21.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] ref B L1: 84.4% 15.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc50180a600] kb/s:1017.91
```

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: is the original frame rate 30 or 29.97 ?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-frame_timecode

Comment: the input is just an image, so there is no "original" frame rate. It's controlled in `image2` by the `-framerate` param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but in case someone else (like me) stumbles upon it, the answer is that the time code skips you see are not an error, but work as intended.

Since you have specified 29.97 fps drop frame (by using a semicolon in the timecode) the two-frame skip is according to the specification (read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMPTE_timecode#Drop_frame_timecode).

In short: Since 29.97 is a fractional speed, and a video file cannot contain fractional frames, frames have to be dropped to maintain a correlation between the time code and wall clock time. Note that no actual video frames are dropped, only time codes are skipped. The specification says that on the first second of every minute, the first two frames (zero and one) are skipped, except for when the minute value is divisible by ten.

So seeing the time code go from 00:00:59:29 to 00:01:00:02 is expected behaviour. In order not to get this you have to switch to another frame rate, and write the time code using only colons: 00:00:00:00.

Comment: I would still think that specifying `-r 30` would give a 30fps output, not 29.97. Thanks for clarifying the spec, that does indeed seem to be what was happening!

Answer (score 0):

I found a StackOverflow post on the same topic; I think that solution is a little more elegant, so [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364861/frame-number-overlay-with-ffmpeg/15369938#15369938).

What method are you using to examine the video? Have you confirmed somehow that it is the video itself at fault, as opposed to the video decoder skipping the frames?

Comment: That shows the frame number, which does increment normally. I was actually putting both of those on the image, but trimmed down my command for simplicity. I'm really looking for a human readable time though.

Comment: As pointed out by Psycogeek, it may be a 'drop frame' display issue, but I'm not sure because I never work in NTSC rates.